# Is using a radiator to warm water inefficient and if so why

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: the radiator]

I'm currently designing a Hottub for my scouting. This isn't the first time we are doing this. In the past, we build a wood stove around a radiator as shown above. Now I'm wondering if this is efficient. I've read that a radiator uses convection where warm air goes up and warm water cools down. We use the radiator to warm up water my applying warm air.

Any great thoughts about this system are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

So ideally, you would want to counterflow the hot air and water. But the problem here is capacity. The efficiency gains from counterflow designs are only significant when you have gobs of capacity and not much in the way of temperature differences. Since you don't want to boil the water, and you really just need to maximize the amount of heat transfer, and the wood stove is capable of boiling the water, you would apply parallel flow here. The hot air can't boil the cool feedwater, and you design it so the air cools to the point it can't boil the hot side either. This is a matter of controlling the water flow and airflow at the design stage.

Hot tub heaters typically are several times the size of a house furnace. So trying to get that kind of heat to transfer though a single radiator is going to be tough. We used 210,000 btu heaters for the tubs at a resort in Florida where I worked. Hot water cast iron radiators work at about 170 btu per segment. You can bump this up quite a bit using forced hot air and greater water flow, but you still have a capacity problem. You are short by a factor of 100.

You also have to be extremely careful that the heater materials are compatible with the water treatment chemicals for whatever type of spa you have. The spa may need a chemistry that can't be tolerated by the metals in the radiator at the temps you need to run it at as a heater. Plastered tile and concrete spas are the toughest and require SS plumbing throughout to handle the chemicals. Plastic and fiberglass spas are a bit easier.

Comment: Would a copper spiral be better?

Comment: If plastic or fiberglass spa and fresh water, not salt, it can be made to work. Beware of the staining potential of the copper. It can ruin the finish of a spa very quickly. You have to use treatment chemicals that are safe for copper coils. I believe most commercial heater copper coils are sealed or coated on the inner surface. I don't know what the coating is.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I have seen is where people have made a hot tub in the garden and built a small woodstove below the level of the tub that has a small water jacket or coil which is directly connected to the tub water.

Once the woodstove is lit it heats the water using thermosyphon flow (all pipes slope so the flow is not impeded), once the tub is hot enough - stop adding wood ...

No controls needed and have the drain at the lowest point...